# Node.js runs fine with alias but not /usr/bin/node?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, node.js

When I do `/usr/bin/node /root/twitch/dakbot/bot.js` it gives me an error about a module.

It seems whatever dependency that one of my `requires` uses is incompatible with an old version of node. So I did `sudo npm install -g n` and `sudo n latest`.

Now Im on node 16.16.0 on ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Now when I do `node /root/twitch/dakbot/bot.js` it runs fine without error. But when I try to do `/usr/bin/node /root/twitch/dakbot/bot.js` or `/usr/bin/nodejs /root/twitch/dakbot/bot.js` it gives me the same error it was giving originally.

Why doesnt `/usr/bin/node` or `/usr/bin/nodejs` use the correct version of node but `node /root/twitch/dakbot/bot.js` does? I'm trying to set up supervisord to keep 3 different node scripts running but I cant get them to start because of this.

Comment: Check where `node` points to with `which node`

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/node` I see the problem now. Thank you.

Comment: Are you running node as root or does your normal user have access to the /root directory?

Comment: Im running it as root. This isnt production its just a homelab environment so I do everything under root and change it later.

Comment: At one point over the years you will destroy your system, I can guarantee you that

Comment: This is a homelab environment where I am meant to break things. Im not worried. I lose nothing from breaking a homelab instance when I can just click "Install from template" in a matter of 2 seconds. I've had my homelab running for over 3 years now and have had 0 catastrophic unrecoverable errors from running things as root. Thats the beauty of virtualization. Wipe and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have multiple versions of node installed in different directories. Check to which binary `node` points with `which node`
or `type node`

Answer (score 0):

multiple versions of node,  exec command to check

```
where node
```

will print all node of your installed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).